# Angularjs Filter search text input with a validation rule

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-filter

Now, I have a very typical filter usage example:

```
...
Search: <input ng-model="searchText">
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
       <td>{{friend}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
...
```

This works very well until I put a regular expression rule to `input` tag,  now the codes:

```
...
Search: <input ng-model="searchText" ng-pattern='/John|Mary|Mike|Adam/'>
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
       <td>{{friend}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
...
```

[See this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/13gVY5k1fvDYj7d58ldO?p=preview)

Unless you passed the validation rule, this filter then start to work, it seems that the validation rule prevents the keywords being passed to the filter until the keywords meet the regex rule, what I expected is the validation only takes effect when the searchText lost its focus.

I'm now using a very ugly workaround, it's something like `dynamic ng-pattern`, I put the expression into a parameter like `$scope.regex=/John|Mary|Mike|Adam/`, then searchText change to `<input ng-model="searchText" ng-pattern='regex' ng-focus="regex=''" ng-blur="regex = /John...../">`.

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [**ng-model-options**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) API which has options to update the `ng-model` on various event or delay.

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FHuZIrDUWH7sGD6Sgkv1?p=preview)

Comment: yes, this `ng-model-options` is the right thing i expected, in fact I need to put `ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }"` to solve my issue. thanks

Comment: @z.Neeson Glad to help you..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Probably you're looking for this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

**Example** (copied from official site)

The following example shows how to override immediate updates. Changes on the inputs within the form will update the model only when the control loses focus (blur event). If escape key is pressed while the input field is focused, the value is reset to the value in the current model.

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="userForm">
    <label>Name:
      <input type="text" name="userName"
             ng-model="user.name"
             ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
             ng-keyup="cancel($event)" />
    </label><br />
    <label>Other data:
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.data" />
    </label><br />
  </form>
  <pre>user.name = <span ng-bind="user.name"></span></pre>
</div>
```